# Passing a Python object to Reactjs

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I'm writing a web app and using `Flask` as the back end and `React` as the front end.
I'm able to pass single data from `Flask`, write it on a page, and fetch it with a hook from `React`. I would like to create a class object from `Python` and fetch it from `React` keeping its properties.
**For example:**
I want to create a `student` in `Python` and show its properties with React on my homepage. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Set up a view that returns a representation of the Python object as JSON (`flask.jsonify`), then use e. g. `fetch()` in Javascript to access that endpoint.